# Using GitLab Runner for compiling and pushing

Tags: git, bash, gulp, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a simple (when built) HTML & CSS site source hosted on my own GitLab server. What I would like to do is when a build passes is have it pushed to a git directory that I specify. I use Gulp to build my files so the workflow I can image is such:

Push local files up to `dev` branch while excluding my `node_modules` and the built files used to serve the site in a folder called `app`. When I want to merge `dev` into `master` a runner starts to make sure everything is OK, then when it has been built successfully, merge into `master` then push the files I need to serve the site into a directory using Git and bash.

I tried to get this going with the following `gitlab-ci.yml` file, but nothing seems to be happening:

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
   - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install

stages:
  - build_deploy

build_&_deploy_app:
  stage: build_deploy
  only:
   - master
  script:
   - gulp
```

Comment: First of all, when you say "*nothing seems to be happening*", you mean... a) the build doesn't start b) it starts but there is no log c) it fails d) it succeeds but the expected actions are seemingly not performed?

Comment: @cascaval the build doesn't start at all, not giving any errors or moving any files

Comment: Doesn't the build page tell you any particular error (a runner not available, a syntax error in .gitlab-ci.yml)? When you open Settings -> Runners page of your project, is a runner enabled there? What is its status (it should have a green dot)? On the Builds page, click on the "CI Lint" button and paste there content of your full .gitlab-ci.yml to check for errors in case what you added here is just a part of it (your sample is valid).

Comment: @cascaval Builds page says "No builds to show." A runner is enabled and is active with green. The CI-lint is valid per [this image](http://imgur.com/H2GJ3KQ). My SO question has the full `yml` file.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no other idea why you would have no log whatsoever while a runner would be online and available.

Comment: @cascaval Ok. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: `When I want to merge dev into master a runner starts to make sure everything is OK`

So, if you want to build *before* the branch is merged in master, you cannot have `only:
   - master`. This means it builds only master branch, not everything you try to merge in master....